# Syntax error for simple text recommender system

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, recommendation-engine

I'm getting this syntax error when defining a function for a simple text recommender system. I feel like it's something simple I'm overlooking.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# define tfidvectorizer
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, 
            strip_accents='unicode', analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
            ngram_range=(1, 3), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1,
            stop_words = 'english')

# fills with empty string
df.description = df.description.fillna('')

# fit TF-IDF on 'description' text
tfv_matrix = tfv.fit_transform(df.description)

tfv_matrix.shape
```

Out:    (86, 1033)

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import sigmoid_kernel

# compute sigmoid kernel
sig = sigmoid_kernel(tfv_matrix, tfv_matrix)

# reverse mapping of indices and strain names
indices = pd.Series(df.index, index=df.name_ocp.drop_duplicates()

# define recommendation function
def give_rec(strain, sig=sig):
    # get index corresponding to name_ocp
    idx = indices[strain]

    # get pairwsie similarity scores 
    sig_scores = list(enumerate(sig[idx]))

    # sort strains 
    sig_scores = sorted(sig_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # scores of 10 most similar strains
    sig_scores = sig_scores[1:11]

    # strain name indices
    strain_indices = [i[0] for i in sig_scores]

    # top 10 most similar strains
    return df.name_ocp.iloc[strain_indices]
```

Out:

```
File "<ipython-input-68-bf5092b4ce7d>", line 10
    def give_rec(strain, sig=sig):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The 'def' and function name are both their appropriate colors in the jupyter notebook. Spacing seems fine. Not sure what the deal is. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: close your bracket on the line before.

Comment: I just realized what the problem was before seeing somebody had just commented it